# How to count unique values for each row in a table in R?

Tags: r

My table g is:

```
g
      ID     GROUP
1     123      A
2     656      A
3     456      A
4     123      A
5     456      B
6     789      A
7     453      B
8     123      C
9     720      D
10    456      E
11    453      A
12    863      F
```

I would like to know how many unique GROUPs is related to each ID.

---

I would like to get the output as below. 
Column x should give me an amount of unique GROUPs

```
      ID       x
1    123       2      # as there are 2 unique GROUPs: A(twice) and C
2    453       2      # as it is B and A - 2 unique GROUPS
3    456       3      # as it is A, B, E
4    656       1      # as it is A
5    720       1      # as it is D
6    789       1      # as it is A
7    863       1      # as it is F
```

### ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

Examples of trying to solve above:

1.

```
agg<-aggregate(g$GROUP, by=list(ID=g$ID), unique)
agg
      ID        x
1    123     2, 6     # amount of digits in column x tells me how many GROUPs 
2    453     1, 2     # are related to single ID. 
3    456  2, 1, 4     # Numbers stand for: B  A  F  E  D  C
4    656        2                        # 1  2  3  4  5  6
5    720        5                       
6    789        2
7    863        3

agg$x
$`0`
[1] A C
Levels: B A F E D C
$`1`
[1] B A
...
...
```

2.

```
ggg <- aggregate(g$GROUP, by=list(ID=g$ID), paste, collapse=",")

     ID           x
1    123      A,A,C      # I want to count unique values (A,C)=2
2    453        B,A
3    456      A,B,E
4    656          A
5    720          D
6    789          A
7    863          F
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
table(unique(g)$ID)
#123 453 456 656 720 789 863 
#  2   2   3   1   1   1   1
```

Alternatively,

```
data.frame(table(unique(g)$ID))
#  Var1 Freq
#1  123    2
#2  453    2
#3  456    3
#4  656    1
#5  720    1
#6  789    1
#7  863    1
```

Answer (score 3):

```
library(data.table)

dt = as.data.table(g)

# using `keyby` instead of `by` to get sorted results
dt[, length(unique(GROUP)), keyby = ID]
#    ID V1
#1: 123  2
#2: 453  2
#3: 456  3
#4: 656  1
#5: 720  1
#6: 789  1
#7: 863  1


# or if you want them combined in a string like in OP:
dt[, paste(unique(GROUP), collapse = ","), keyby = ID]
#    ID    V1
#1: 123   A,C
#2: 453   B,A
#3: 456 A,B,E
#4: 656     A
#5: 720     D
#6: 789     A
#7: 863     F
```

Comment: I think he just wants `setDT(g)[, length(unique(GROUP)), by = list(ID)]` (as suggested in his desired output)

Comment: @DavidArenburg you're right, I got distracted by the bottom part :)

Comment: Small improvement: I'd suggest `unique(dt)[, .N, keyby=ID]`. It avoids memory allocation for each group - doing `unique(GROUP)`.

Comment: @Arun, that's a nice suggestion, but I'm afraid no one will understand or be able to reproduce this syntax except you and eddie :)

Comment: @DavidArenburg, I've simplified it a bit. But I'm not sure I follow the difficulty. Aggregate *after* unique, instead of aggregate *with* unique..

Comment: David Arenburg - yes, that is what I needed
       ,eddi - your first table is what I was expecting

Answer (score 3):

A little trick using the [`sqldf` package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sqldf/index.html):

```
# I had to rename the 'group'  column to avoid problems
> g <- data.frame(
    id=c(123, 656, 456, 123, 456, 789, 453, 123, 720, 456, 453, 863),
    group_id=c('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'A', 'F')
  )

> library(sqldf)

> sqldf('select id, count(distinct group_id) as unique_groups from g group by ID')
   id unique_groups
1 123             2
2 453             2
3 456             3
4 656             1
5 720             1
6 789             1
7 863             1
```

Comment: For simplicity, [Frank's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25436418/how-to-count-unique-values-for-each-row-in-a-table-in-r/25436553#25436553) is quite a good one. However, if you are familiar with SQL, `sqldf` will be quite helpful

Comment: Yes, Frank's answer is simple and I like that one, but it is good to know your way too

Answer (score 3):

Using `aggregate` as in your question:

```
with(g, aggregate(GROUP ~ ID, FUN = function(x) length(unique(x))))
#   ID GROUP
#1 123     2
#2 453     2
#3 456     3
#4 656     1
#5 720     1
#6 789     1
#7 863     1
```

A `dplyr` alternative:

```
library(dplyr)
g %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarise(count = n_distinct(GROUP))
#Source: local data frame [7 x 2]
#
#   ID count
#1 123     2
#2 453     2
#3 456     3
#4 656     1
#5 720     1
#6 789     1
#7 863     1
```

Comment: Interesting (and confusing). I just did a benchmark on relatively bigger data out of curiosity.. and `n_distinct()` seems *slower* than `length(unique())`... [Here's the gist](https://gist.github.com/arunsrinivasan/49d77143af9bf4259811).

Comment: @Arun, I also made a small benchmark and that seemed to indicate that `n_distinct` is faster when the number of unique groups is relatively low, while `length(unique())` was faster for larger number of unique groups.. but that was only a very quick benchmark.

Comment: I've asked Hadley/Romain. 1000 groups doesn't seem a lot.

Comment: @Arun, right, would be interesting to hear what they say.

Answer (score 1):

tapply can also be used here for simple code and clean output:

```
with(g, tapply(GROUP, ID, function(x)length(unique(x))))
123 453 456 656 720 789 863 
  2   2   3   1   1   1   1
```